# Java Web application successfully deployed on GlassFish but 404 when one accesses to it

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

First I must say I do not know much about java enterprise edition. Well, I have a web application which is mostly a JavaBean, a JPA entity, two JavaServer Faces files and a ManagedBean controller, I'm using Maven in eclipse and I have a Glassfish server installed on my machine(which is running Arch Linux).

When I deploy the war file into glassfish I get a `successfully deployed` message, but when I try to access my web application which should be on `http://localhost:8080/chapter10-2.0` I get a Http 404 Not Found response, I have try a lot to solve this by myself but I don't get it yet, so I would appreciate a lot some help, thank in advance.

My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>chapter10</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>newBook.xhtml</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>newBook.faces</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Obviously the file you're requesting is not where you expect it to be. Post your web app directory structure here

Comment: Indeed, the problem was that I used the default location for my webapp directory that eclipse created, so it created the webapp directory outside the src/main directory, for that it didn't find my web files. I just moved it and everything is OK, at least with that. Thankz.